# case-control study with cross-sectional data

Tags: logistic, cross-section, observational-study

I have a General Practitioner dataset for several thousand patients, taken at a single snapshot in time (let's call it time X). Patients that have died since the database was set up are therefore not included in the dataset. Being GP data, it was collected prospectively.  The data includes dates of diagnoses of various conditions, but not date of registration to the GP practice.

I have been asked to examine patients with a given condition (at time X) and compare the exposure of various factors to controls. Is this study design a nested case-control study, even though the original study from which the cases and controls will be selected is not strictly a cohort study? Or is this simply a cross-sectional design, with some temporal covariates included? My plan is to match 4-5 controls per case and perform (conditional) logistic regression. Is this viable under this study design?

Thanks.